# How to use loop to create a group of list containers in python

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops

Is it possible to create a group of list/array from another list.

Have

```
L = ['a','b','c','d','e',]
```

would like

```
a=[]
b=[]
c=[]
d=[]
e=[]
```

Comment: What **is** `a`? Is it a string (`"a"`)?

Comment: What problem do you try to solve with that?

Comment: I don't understand the use case.  If you don't already know what the strings in L will be, if you create free-standing variables not related to each other in any way, how will the rest of your code reference them?  By going back to L and looping through it?  If so, why is having the containers in a dict less convenient than this?

Comment: I see your point, How would I fill/modify tables in list/array form vs isolated.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but my suggestion is to set up the dict like delnan suggested below, and then you would add to each list by going: d['a'].append(whatever)

Comment: I'm a newbie, I dont use dict very often. need a sol which could be applied to numpy.

Comment: How do you mean "applied to numpy"?  Some context may be helpful-- e.g., where the elements of L are coming from and what you are planning to do with the container lists once you have them.

Comment: Each container list/array will hold data and then some will be updated other will not updated.  Then further data mining. Each list container may be manipilated with numpy. The containers need to be indpendent.

Comment: A similar working model would EBAY auctions, each independent. with daily ending and dif pricings.

Comment: Each value stored in the dict as delnan described below *will* be an independent list.  Where is L coming from?  Unless you have no choice in the matter, it may be easier just to create it as a dict instead of a list in the first place.

Comment: All these expansions and refinements to your question should have been part of your question to begin with; please at least edit them into the question now.

Comment: List is coming from outside program...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *could*, with some hackery, create variables from strings. However, this is almost never a good idea. Just use a `dict`, which is exactly that without all the headaches that come from confusing your code's namespace with a collection for (possibly user-provided) data.

```
d = {}
for name in L:
    d[name] = []
```

(In Python 2.7 and 3.x, you can write this as a single expression thanks to dictionary comprehensions: `{name: [] for name in L}`.)

Comment: need containers in list form or array form , 2.6v

Comment: @user428862: Then provide a complete example. What you showed in the question isn't a list, it's a bunch of assignments.

Comment: @delman. ok, its assignments....I have something that looks like L. I want to create list containers with the elements in L. which will be later filled with data. Clear? I tried %s, with loop it failed.

Comment: So you want to create and assign variables dynamically, named after the strings in `L`? Well, that's what my answer does. It's the one sane way to do it.

Comment: Yes, it does. How would isolate 'a', fill it, isolate 'b' fill it....I was thinking a = [], this is a : []. thnks

Comment: to fill the a entry: d['a'] = []

Comment: No need to wait for 2.7/3.0 to build a dictionary in a single expression: dict((name, []) for name in L). In general it's preferable to an imperative build.

Answer (score 5):

Here's one way:

```
>>> vars={}
>>> for x in L:
...     vars[x]=list()
... 
>>> vars
{'a': [], 'c': [], 'b': [], 'e': [], 'd': []}

>>> locals().update(vars)
>>> a
[]
>>> b
[]
```

This updates the `locals` and adds the new items. But I would simply keep the `dict` named `vars` if I were you. Better to have explicit data structures instead of messing with `locals` or `globals`.

Comment: Do I need to use dict. I was hoping to have "a" free standing, instead of vars[0].

Comment: @user428862: I think it is a better idea. Can save confusion down the line. This way variables defined in code are clear and separate from variables (i.e. `dict` entries) defined during runtime. What if you already have a variable called 'a' and then try to dynamically add 'a' with some other value int `locals`? What if the variables are named based on input and so you have no idea what new variables will be created and may overwrite variables you need in your code?